# Big Sur 11.2 keeps forgetting Location Permission for Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome, big-sur, privacy, geolocation

Seemingly every week Chrome will lose it's location permission and require me to re-check its box in the Privacy settings. Did I do something to make the exception temporary? Does it reset when Chrome updates? Can I say I permanently trust it?

Comment: This could help you https://superuser.com/questions/591758/how-do-i-make-chrome-forget-a-no-to-geolocation-on-a-site

Comment: It's a bug in chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1143807